# SQL server alternative for Oracle's all_scheduler_jobs

Tags: sql-server

I am replicating application developed in Oracle to SQL server.

I need equivalents for Oracle sources:

- all_scheduler_jobs
- all_scheduler_running_jobs
- all_scheduler_job_run_details

I am building it from these, but maybe some has already done it:

- msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
- msdb.dbo.sysjobs
- msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory

I am mostly interested in timing, scheduling and status information.

Comment: Also look at `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` and `msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules`

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [`sp_help_job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and the underlying things they ultimately call (`sys.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs` and `dbo.sp_get_composite_job_info`):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job;

EXEC sys.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, 'sa';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_get_composite_job_info 
  @job_id = 0x08549D549D494D4AA5802BE0A202EA52;
```

Those are relevant calls to get the information for all jobs (or a single job), but you can also view the source code for the first and last stored procedure, which will help you reverse engineer the queries you'll need to simulate a view.

[Relevant thread, perhaps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65f33d7c-a954-4554-b714-aaad37cfc653/xpsqlagentenumjobs-documentation?forum=transactsql).